Adjusting the title page in a thesis
I'm writing my MSc thesis and I'm facing some troubles. I have two supervisors. I need to list their names and affiliations side by side as shown in the attached screenshot.
How can I achieve this? So far, I have the following code for the title page
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=0.85in, headsep=22pt, footskip=0.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\vspace*{1cm}

{\LARGE \textbf{The title} \par} 
\vspace*{1.5cm}
\textsc{By} 
\vspace*{0.7cm}
{\Large \textsc{Hussein Eid Abdelgelil Elsawy}}
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{spacing}{1.2}
\textsc{A thesis submitted \\ 
to \\
Faculty Of Science \\
In Partial Fulfillment Of The Requirements For \\
The Degree Of Master Of Science \\
(Pure Mathematics) \\
Faculty Of Science, Cairo University
}
\end{spacing}
\vspace*{2cm}
\textsc{Supervisors}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}

Also, does my code look good? or can be written in a better way?


One method is using two-column table.

Just use two tabular environments.
Also, the spacing between elements is too small. I'd use stretching factors so the page is better filled.
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany]{book}
\usepackage[
  left=1in,
  right=1in,
  top=1in,
  bottom=0.85in,
  headsep=22pt,
  footskip=0.75cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names, svgnames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} 

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\singlespacing

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

{\LARGE \textbf{The title} \\[\stretch{2}]}

\textsc{By} \\[\stretch{1}]

{\Large \textsc{Hussein Eid Abdelgelil Elsawy}\\[\stretch{4}]}

\textsc{A thesis submitted \\[1ex]
to \\[1ex]
Faculty Of Science \\
In Partial Fulfillment \\
 Of The Requirements For \\
The Degree Of Master Of Science \\
(Pure Mathematics) \\
Faculty Of Science, Cairo University\\[\stretch{3}]}

\textsc{Supervisors}\\[2ex]

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\bfseries Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Laila F. Abd.\@ Elal \\
Department of Mathematics \\
Faculty of Science \\
Cairo University
\end{tabular}\hfil
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\bfseries Prof.\@ Dr.\@ Nasser H. Sweilam \\
Department of Mathematics \\
Faculty of Science \\
Cairo University
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{\stretch{3}}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}

Note that inputenc is no longer necessary, as UTF-8 is the default.

Adapt the factors to your taste. You can use also fractional values, not necessarily integers, such as 1.5.

Excuse me. I need the font style to be textsc in the part including the names of the supervisors and their affiliations (like the rest of the title page).

@HusseinEid You won't get boldface, of course. Just type \scshape after the title line and you'll get small caps everywhere even without \textsc.

Thanks for your help.
